# Order by child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have Rails 3.1.2 app with a hierarchical relationship that looks like this: Categories -> Discussions -> Comments

A category has many discussions and a discussion has many comments.

On the categories show view, I am displaying a list of all the discussions belonging to that category. I'm using Kaminari for pagination. So far I have managed to order them by the time when the discussion was created, like this:

`@discussions = Discussion.where(:category_id => @category.id).order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])`

However, I would rather order the discussions by the time of the most recent comment belonging to that discussion, like most forums do, with the most recently updated discussions appearing at the top of the screen. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Category < Model
  has_many :discussions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :through => :discussions, :dependent => :destroy

  def latest_comment_time
    comments.last.created_at
  end
end
```

Now you can order Discussions with `Discussion.all.sort_by(&:latest_comment_time)`.

Comment: This didn't work. I should add that there is a polymorphic association between discussions and comments (discussions are a commentable), although I'm not sure if that matters. The code you mentioned `@forum.comments.last` would seem to be getting comments, whereas I want to get the discussions but order them by the last comment created in each discussion.

Comment: I took out the distracting chaff to just focus on what I was trying to explain.

Comment: How would the discussions be fetched? I've tried `@discussions = Discussion.order('latest_comment.created_at')` but it throws up a `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column` error.

Comment: Try changing `def latest_comment` to `def latest_comment_time; comments.last.created_at; end`. Then you can do `Discussion.all.sort_by(&:latest_comment_time)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make sure that when comments are posted, it should set the `updated_at` column for the discussion to the current timestamp. If you have wrote all the code yourself then it should be easily accomplished with the use of the `touch` option for associations. Like this for example:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, :touch => true

  ...
end
```

That way you can keep sorting the discussions on the updated_at attribute without joining other tables or doing it in additional ruby code. It is probably a lot faster to do it that way.

If you use a gem or something for your commentable function then I can't say for sure how that should be configured but it should have some configuration option for it.

Comment: The problem with `:touch` is that it also triggers when a Comment is saved. Imagine a Forum if you could bump a Topic just by editing any post in the Topic.

Comment: That would be a problem if it indeed is an undesired result. I still think it is the most efficient way and if the touch should be conditional then it can also be moved to an `after_create` callback or other solutions. I'm generally for doing all kind of sorting on the database level instead of leaving it up to the controllers.